# Implementing a progress bar in android with specific values doesn't work

Tags: android, progress-bar

I tried to implement a layout that works like a progress bar. I want to it to be able to be set to any level I want in special cases. For example to be set to 20.

```
   @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0x123) {
            mCDrawable.setLevel(mProgress);
        }
    }
    Runnable a= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0x123);
            mProgress = 20;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(18);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  };
  public void add(int num){
    Thread s = new Thread(a);
    s.start();

}
```

I do it by calling the "add" function.
     The problem is that in a "while" where the progress changes continueslly it works:

```
  Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while (running) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0x123);
            if (mProgress > MAX_PROGRESS) {
                mProgress = 0;
            }
            mProgress += 100;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(18);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What is the difference? How can I set it to a specific value otherwise?

---edit----:
  I tried this code and it still doesnt work:

```
public void add(int num){
    int lvl = mClipDrawable.getLevel();
    Log.d("______________", "the first was "+lvl);
    lvl += 100;
    if (lvl > 10000) {
        lvl = 1000;
    }
    Log.d("______________", "set to "+lvl);
    mClipDrawable.setLevel(lvl);
}
```

the first level was 0 and it set 100..

Comment: why are you using a background Thread? what actually is your goal?

Comment: How else ca i do it? It meant for continious changing the level..

Comment: My goal is to be able to set any progress level at any time

Comment: so call Drawable#setLevel(lvl), whats the problem?

Comment: It does not changes the level.. it changes only in continious changing..

Comment: I cant find the difference but it doesnt work...

Comment: continious changing? post your code with setLevel

Comment: in the while.. I posted that code, you can see there the example that does not work and the second one works

Comment: setLevel is called from handleMessage

Comment: so you are saying the the code like this http://pastebin.com/aEr7j2ky doesnt work?

Comment: I tried the code I added in the edit, like the code you sent, but still doesnt work

Comment: did you run my code?  didn't it work?

Comment: It worked! thanks! The problem was that I took too small range